# Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.PublishException: Cannot publish artifact 'xodus-samples.jar' as it does not exist

Tags: gradle

I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.PublishException: Cannot publish artifact 'xodus-samples.jar' (/Jetbrains/xodus/samples/build/libs/xodus-samples.jar) as it does not exist.
        at org.gradle.internal.component.external.ivypublish.DefaultArtifactPublisher.isValidToPublish(DefaultArtifactPublisher.java:118)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.external.ivypublish.DefaultArtifactPublisher.addConfigurations(DefaultArtifactPublisher.java:95)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.external.ivypublish.DefaultArtifactPublisher.toPublishMetaData(DefaultArtifactPublisher.java:84)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.external.ivypublish.DefaultArtifactPublisher.publish(DefaultArtifactPublisher.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyContextualArtifactPublisher.lambda$publish$0(IvyContextualArtifactPublisher.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:139)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyContextualArtifactPublisher.publish(IvyContextualArtifactPublisher.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload.upload(Upload.java:66)
        ... 183 more
```

When trying to do `./gradlew install` for this script https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/blob/master/build.gradle

What could be wrong in my process? How can I manage to make it install correctly?